# AWS cloudformation pass parameters to EC2 environment

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have an EC2 instance template I'm creating that will be running a specific application. I want to be able to pass parameters through to this application's startup script I have being executed in my templates UserData.

Ideally there would be a way for me to convert the specified parameters into either:
A) Environment variables on the ec2 instance that I would access in the startup script
B) Usable variables inside of my UserData script.

Here's a simplified template of what I would like to accomplish... Haven't found any aws docs saying it can be done:

```
Resources:
  GitlabRunner:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Description: "AWS stack for a serivce"
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: "#!/bin/bash\nmy-service $TAGS"

Parameters:
  Tags:
    Type: String
    Default: asd
    Description: Comma delimited list of tags
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario can be achieved using `!Sub` (notice the substitution syntax `${..}`). For exemple:

```
Resources:
  GitlabRunner:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Description: "AWS stack for a serivce"
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub "#!/bin/bash\nmy-service ${Tags}"

Parameters:
  Tags:
    Type: String
    Default: asd
    Description: Comma delimited list of tags
```

You can avoid having to input everything on a single line using `|`. For exemple:

```
...
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash
    my-service ${Tags}
    echo hello world
```